# Django update_or_create raises IntegrityError within Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following `ModelSerializer` with a `create` method. In this method I call the model's `update_or_create` method. But when I do this, the serializer's validation raises the error

`rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: [{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='The fields user_id, capacity_id must make a unique set.', code='unique')]}, {}]`.

I thought that since I'm using `update_or_create`, it would find the row that matches validated data's `user_id` and `capacity_id`, and then update that row. But the validation runs before create, and the data is not valid because of the unique constraint. So how do I ignore this constraint?

```
class ActivatedCapacitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    capacity_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ActivatedCapacity
        fields = ('user_id', 'capacity_id', 'active')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        activated_capacity = ActivatedCapacity.objects.update_or_create(
            user_id=validated_data['user_id'],
            capacity_id=validated_data['capacity_id'],
            defaults = {
                'active': validated_data['active']
            }
        )

        return activated_capacity
```

Models.py

```
class ActivatedCapacity(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    capacity_id = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user_id', 'capacity_id',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to include in the serializer's `class Meta` an empty validators list, so it will override the model's default validators.

```
class ActivatedCapacitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    capacity_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ActivatedCapacity
        fields = ('user_id', 'capacity_id', 'active')
        validators = []
     
    ...
```